# Webpack, React, JSX, Babel - Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

This is what I have, using ExpressJS:

```
|-- app
|   |-- index.js
|-- node_modules
|   |-- babel-core
|   |-- babel-loader
|   |-- babel-preset-react
|   |-- express
|   |-- react
|   |-- react-dom
|   |-- webpack
|-- public
|   |-- js
|   |   |-- app.js
|   |-- index.html
|-- .babelrc
|-- index.js
|-- package.json
|-- webpack.config.js
```

/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './app/index.js'
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            include: __dirname + '/app',
            loader: "babel-loader",
            query: {
                presets:['react']
            }
        }]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "app.js",
        path: __dirname + '/public/js'
    }
};
```

/app/index.js

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var People = React.createClass({
    ...
});
ReactDOM.render(<People />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

/.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

When I run webpack I get:

> Module parse failed: /app/index.js Unexpected token <
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

When I replace `<People />` with `React.createElement(People, {})` it works just fine.

I have the `babel-preset-react` module. I have `presets:['react']` with the `babel-loader` loader. I have the `.babelrc` file.

Why can webpack/babel not parse the `<People />` JSX..?

Comment: What versions of Babel/React are you using?

Comment: Try adding `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/` as your test. Perhaps it's not parsing JSX extensions.

Comment: @Andy babel-core: 6.7.4, babel-loader: 6.2.4, babel-preset-react: 6.5.0, react: 0.14.7, react-dom: 0.14.7

Comment: @lux Just tried that, no luck, same message. I don't have any files with the extension `.jsx`, only `.js`.

Comment: What if you change `loader: "babel-loader"` to simply `loader: "babel"`? That's how my webpack config reads.

Comment: @Andy No change, same error. I was guessing that `babel-loader` points to the name of the module folder in `node_modules`.

Comment: [Here's my webpack/babel/react set up](https://github.com/andywillis/react2). This has been working fine. Perhaps take a look and see if it differs from yours somehow.

Comment: Try to remove  `query: {
                presets:['react']
            }` from your webback config

Comment: It seems like there might be a conflict between your webpack.config.js and .babelrc files. I'd get rid of .babelrc and add the react preset to your list of loaders in webpack.config.js.

Comment: Just tried both of those, removed `presets` from the config, and renamed `.babelrc`. Not at the same time obviously, one at a time so the other was there... I know the way I have it looks like it's trying to do it both ways at the same time, but only having one (either) still doesn't work.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the link, I've had a look... I really can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with my `include` path. I had:

```
include: __dirname + '/app'
```

I'm now using `path`:

```
include: path.join(__dirname, '/app')
```

Which works! I'm on Windows, don't know if that makes a difference. Think I'll start using `path` routinely from now on.

Would've been nice for the webpack error to be something like `Can't find include folder/files`.

Comment: I'm on mac and was having the same problem